# Looping Issue -Store the data which is of a different format

Tags: r, loops, data-structures, time-series, forecasting

I am having some trouble storing the data after it runs. The code is picking the files up correctly and running the forecast model but it somehow stores the value for the last file. All the others are lost. Is there anyway that I can have all the results stored in a different array. The problem is that the format of the output is in "forecast" format and because of that I am getting stuck on it. I have looked through all the websites but couldn't find something like that.

Here is the code:

```
library(forecast)
library(quantmod)
library(forecast)

fileList <-as.array(length(50))
Forecast1 <- as.array(length(50))


fileList<-list.files(path ='C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\wOOLWORTHS\\',recursive =T, pattern = ".csv")
i<- integer()
j<-integer()
i=1
setwd("C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\wOOLWORTHS\\")

while (i<51)
{
  a<-fileList[i]
  print(a)
  a <- read.csv(a)

  fileSales<-a$sales
  fileTransform<-log(fileSales)
  plot.ts(fileTransform)
  result1<-HoltWinters(fileTransform,beta = FALSE,gamma =FALSE,seasonal ="multiplicative",optim.control =TRUE)
  result2<-forecast.HoltWinters(result1,h=1)
  summary(result1)
  accuracy(result2)

  #Forecast1[i] <- result2(forecast)
  #print(Forecast1[i])
  i=i+1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It may just be how you are storing your results. Try filling an empty list instead (e.g.`Forecast1`):

```
setwd("C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\wOOLWORTHS\\")

library(forecast)
library(quantmod)
library(forecast)

fileList <- list.files(path ='C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\wOOLWORTHS\\',recursive =T, pattern = ".csv")

Forecast1 <- vector(mode="list", 50)

for(i in seq(length(fileList)){
  a <- fileList[[i]]
  #print(a)
  a <- read.csv(a)

  fileSales<-a$sales
  fileTransform<-log(fileSales)
  plot.ts(fileTransform)
  result1<-HoltWinters(fileTransform,beta = FALSE,gamma =FALSE,seasonal ="multiplicative",optim.control =TRUE)
  result2<-forecast.HoltWinters(result1,h=1)
  #summary(result1)
  #accuracy(result2)

  Forecast1[[i]] <- result2
  #print(Forecast1[i])
  print(paste(i, "of", length(fileList), "completed"))
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Marc.. That worked and I got to the final solution. How do I extract the results for this list (Forecast 1 List). I am trying to create a vector of results so that it looks nice and tidy. Is there anyway I could do that? I know there is some function but I can't find it. Thank you

Comment: I'm not familiar with the forecast results objects, but you could probably use some sort of apply function: e.g. `sapply(Forecast1, FUN=function(x){x$res})` , with $res being the part of the results object that you want to return from each object in the list `Forecast1`.